# How to fix: JTS TopologyException: Found null DirectedEdge

Tags: geometry, jts-topology-suite, invalid-data

How can I fix a: `TopologyException: Found null DirectedEdge`?

Initially (sadly), the geometry is invalid.
But then when applying a `geom.buffer(0)` `st_valid(my_geom)` returns true.

Still there are problems with the geometry and I keep getting the exception.

Comment: Is length of edge geometry > 0 ?

Comment: I have many geometries, and indeed many of them are invalid - unfortunately.